# How to validate content-type in mule4

Tags: mule-studio

Hi I am having use case that I want to validate the content-type from request (Validate incoming request ie it has to be xml only if it is other than xml it has to print please check the content). How can we achieve this in mule4

Answer (score 0):

You can get the content-type header from the attributes of the request.

Example

```
<flow name="testContentType">
    <http:listener doc:name="Listener" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/"/>
    <logger message="Content-type: #[attributes.Headers['content-type']]"/>
</flow>
```

You can use the same expression in a choice router or use the value to compare to a specific MIME type in a  validator.